# Play video only in active page of ViewPager

Tags: android

I am displaying videos using `ViewPager`. Each page plays a different video. I would like to play the video only in the active page (other pages should be paused) like in Facebook or Instagram.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();


    if (player == null) {

        prepareplayer(bufferpos, video);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }
}


@Override
public void onPause() {

    super.onPause();

    if( player != null) {

        player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    }

    releaseplayer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the `ViewPager` contains fragments, you can pause the video in the fragment's `onPause()` method and resume it in its `onResume()` method.

Comment: i am using exoplaye in onresume and onpause  i am giving  like this                                          
  @Override
   public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       if (player == null) {
           prepareplayer(bufferpos, video);
           player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
         
       }
       System.out.println("on resume screen"+position);
   }
  
   public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       if(player!=null) {
           player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
       }
       releaseplayer();
   }

Comment: i am facing the same issue , did you resolve the issue????

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. In MainActivity class, I have done like this which plays the video only in the current viewpager and pause the video on other viewpager when viewpager is scrolled. In viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener callback  override method

```
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int  positionOffsetPixels)
        {
    MyFragment fragment=(MyFragment)fragmentAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager,viewPager.getCurrentItem());
         SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer= fragment.getPlayer();
         if(simpleExoPlayer!=null)
         {
             simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
         }
        }
```